# jQuery 1.4.2 triggers click after click has triggered bind

Tags: jquery

Here's my code:

```
select.appendTo('body')[options.open](0, function() {
    $(document).bind('click focus', function(e) {
        if($(e.target).closest(select).length == 0) closeAltSelect();
    });
});
```

The problem is that every time select opens, it closes next moment because as I understand, click that triggers select to open, also triggers click event on body EVEN tho I bind click AFTER click.

It's jQuery 1.4.2. No problems on 1.6+.

[options.open] = open function.

I'd really appriciate your help.

Thank you!

EDIT--------------------------------------------

show doesnt like 0 for duration, added "" (quotes) and now it works.

Thank you!

;)

Comment: select is variable, not element :)

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: I know I delete my comment. Still, it might work with `'select'`. *Edit:* See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing the string `'select'` to `.closest()` instead of the jQuery object. This possibility was only added in jQuery 1.6 (see the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest1)) and therefore does not work in 1.4.2.